# How to add mailcore framework to our iphone project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mailcore

I tried to add mailcore framework to my project which is existing in my library but it's not getting added into it,can any one pls help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](http://alwawee.com/wordpress/2012/06/25/how-to-build-mailcore-framework-on-ios/http://) I wrote instructions, how to run samle project.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [reMail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/). remail uses mailcore, and since its acquisition by google, is open source.

Another way is to actually build [mailcore](https://bitbucket.org/mronge/mailcore/src/d156df4351e7/Resources/GETTING_STARTED.txt).

> GETTING STARTED
>
> The best way to start learning MailCore is by reading through 
>   documentation intro (in index.html)  and the the included example
>   projects.  To run the example projects:
>
> 1. Copy MailCore.framework to your ~/Library/Frameworks folder.
> 2. In each example project, add ~/Library/Frameworks/MailCore.framework  to the list of Linked
>      Frameworks.
> 3. Build it!
>
> The documentation isn't as detailed as I'd like. Sorry about that!  If
>   something isn't clear try reading the source included or contact me.
>
> CONTACT INFO
>
> MailCore by Matt Ronge http://www.mronge.com mronge@mronge.com
>
> LICENSE
>
> Licensed under BSD, see LICENSE.txt for more information.
>
> Based on LibEtPan and work done by Dinh Viet Hoa.

From the [Getting Started](https://bitbucket.org/mronge/mailcore/src/d156df4351e7/Resources/GETTING_STARTED.txt) documentation on the project:

> IPHONE USE
>
> MailCore has an included iPhone
>   target, but it requires some
>   additional compiled binaries (OpenSSL
>   and CyrusSSL). I am unable to
>   currently provide these, however the
>   company Remail is offering the
>   binaries and a compiled copy of
>   MailCore for the iPhone. Contact
>   Remail for more information:
>
> mailcore@remail.com

It seems like you'd need to get those before building against the iPhone target.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the instructions he doesn't say to add the MailCore framework. Just the library. Try it that way.